# Google Compute Instance booting in to emergency mode

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've been handed a Google Compute Instance to manage and after it's first reboot it's immediately gone in to emergency mode.

Is there anyway for me to access a recovery console to continue normal booting or another way I can get around this?

The output of my serial log is [here](https://gist.github.com/dblencowe/2dbeb47599f02e06f20e)

Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: because `Failed to mount /mnt/ssd-30`

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand why though? It's a disk that's been attached to the instance since day 1, although I'm not sure if this machine has ever been rebooted.

Comment: don't know. maybe fs is broken? i guess you can assign it to a new temp instance and check it

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a corrupted device (/mnt/ssd-30). I'd suggest to remove that device from the instance, stop the instance and then start it again.

Comment: You can try to fix the fs on the disk as recommended by Igor instead of deleting and recreating a new disk.

Comment: However, if that is a boot disk? Also, the serial logs stop in "[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel ChanWelcome to emergency mode! AfterGive root password for maintenance
(or type Control-D to continue): " this line, and does not proceed further to start other services like SSHD, so it won't let me login via SSH. Any solution would be greatly appreciated.